# How can configure EthereumJ to connect to the public testnet.?

Tags: clients, testnets, ethereumj

I need to connect to the public testnet via ethereumj 
can anybody help me please.

Comment: It's usually helpful if you include some of the things you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 4):

(I've only worked this out via code inspection, as I can't find anything in the documentation.)
In the file [ethereumj.conf](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/develop/ethereumj-core/src/main/resources/ethereumj.conf) change the line

```
# Network id
networkId = 1
```

to

```
networkId = 2
```

In the same file set the network list by changing the line to set ip.list:

```
  ip.list = [
        "92.51.165.126:30303",
    ]
```

In the same file specify a boot node:

```
active = [
        { url = "enode://e58d5e26b3b630496ec640f2530f3e7fa8a8c7dfe79d9e9c4aac80e3730132b869c852d3125204ab35bb1b1951f6f2d40996c1034fd8c5a69b383ee337f02ddc@92.51.165.126:30303" }
```

Save the genesis json from https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Morden into the folder `resources/genesis` and call it `frontier.json`.